# Deleting a column in Excel from R

Tags: excel, r

I have an xls. file that contains the following information

[image: Excel file]

I want to delete from R columns D and E and of course that the data of F moves to the left. How I can do that in R?
Thanks

Comment: Clarification: Do you just mean how to drop columns once data is in R? Or are you using something to transfer data between R and Excel?

Comment: I just want to read and delete the columns that are in Excel by using R. So the data is not in R.

Comment: Why not just delete them in Excel? Also, how are you getting your data from Excel to R?

Comment: I cannot delete in Excel because the xls file is huge and I need to program a script to delete only some specific columns based in another txt file

Comment: Or you can try to write a VBScript, which deletes your colums and then call it from within R.

Comment: just -1 because the answer is not so simple as it seems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the .xls file into R with one of the several packages (eg. xlsReadWrite:read.xls()), delete the columns :

```
data$Column <- NULL 
or 
data <- data[ ,-c(4,5)]
```

and then write the new data to a .xls file with one of the mentioned packages.

Comment: The only problem I see with this is that any formatting could be lost (colored cells, graphs, tables, reports...).

Comment: The problem as I mentioned is that I want to delete the column and also move the other columns to fill that space

Comment: They will be moved automatically.

Comment: I cannot read like csv because the data in Excel is transformed to a tab separation text when I want to transform it into a text file, any help somebody?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into a csv file and use `read.csv` function to load it in R. Then, you delete the columns you want to and save it with `write.csv`.

Comment: if I do that conversion the other columns will advance the position of the missing ones? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes. However, any formatting will be lost (colors, graphs, borders...)